# php function not working want to get party_name from party id

Tags: php, function

i have party id but i want to get party_name from party table and made a function but its not working can anybody please correct it where i am wrong?

```
 function get_partyname($party)
 {
 global $database;
 $sql = 'SELECT party_name from party WHERE id= '.$party;
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
 extract($row);
 return $party_name;

}



  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table_name ;

  $result = $conn1->query($sql);
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {
    echo $row['id'];
    $party_name = get_partyname($row['party']);
echo $party_name;

 }
```

Comment: You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: my dear friend its clearly mentioned what i want please read title before code

Comment: why are you passing `$row['party']` shouldn't it be `$row['id']`?

Comment: is $table_name value equals to party_name?

Comment: Wreigh i have id stored in $row['party'] in another table if i echo $row['party'] i'll get party id

Comment: Why do you have `global $database` when you're not using it?

Comment: Karlo Kokkak nopes $table_name and party_name both are different

Comment: Edward after removing its not working

Comment: Where is $conn? Is it outside of the function? If it is, you need to add `global $conn`.

Comment: this -  return $party_name; to  return $row['party_name'];

Comment: Thanks Edward its working now :D

Comment: Karlo Kokkak error because i forgot to add global $conn

Comment: @SamirParuthi Please upvote and accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
global $conn;
```

because your database connection cannot be accessed outside the function.

Comment: Thanks Edward Its Working

Comment: @SamirParuthi No problem! Please click the upvote button and the green checkmark next to the post. :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace global $database; with global $conn;.That's it.